# Lua - plugin.google.iap.v3 store.loadProducts() not getting the tittle as intended - corona sdk

Tags: android, plugins, lua, coronasdk

Hi im using the plugin v3 etc but when I try to get the tittle of the item

```
print( event.products[i].title )
```

I recive the title but with a (name of the app) anyone know why is that? I just want the

tittle of the product not

"tittle (name of the app)"

in android console I set the tittle as  eg. "cars" for my game colors

and when I call the method store.loadProducts and then try to get the title I get
"cars (colors)" why is that? and how could I just ask for the title only.

thanks,

testing:

Galaxy S4

Corona daily build: v2014.2323

Answer (score 0):

If there is no attribute or function for just the title, you could parse the string to get the title only:

```
info = event.products[i].title
-- info = "cars (name of app)" -- example
title, appName = string.match(info, "^(%w+) %((.*)%)")
print(title, appName)
```